# Can't "CreateTime" and "UpdateTime" of "firestore" be used as search condition?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to use "firestore" to search for a "Document" by the time it was created, but can't I use the "CreateTime" provided by "firestore" for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries are based on **Indexes** Firestore creates solely based on the fields YOU added to the documents. So for now, the answer is no.